# Problema ao enviar e-mail (com html) usando PHP

Tags: php, html, email

Olá, 
Eu tenho um código em html para enviar no e-mail que no modo normal do html ele apreseta normalmente mas quando envio o email, ao vizualizar no gmail, chega todo errado o html.
Já no Thunderbird o email chega com o html corretamente.

Alguem tem uma solucao para mim?

**Meu código html é:**

```
function html() {
    $r = '
<!-- v 0.1 -->
<head>
    <style>
    .descricao {text-align:center;float:left;width:350px;font-family:Arial;height:100px;border:1px solid green;background-color:white;font-size:40px;color:black;padding:15px;}
    .especificacao {margin-left:3px;float:left;text-align:center;width:350px;font-family:Arial;height:100px;border:1px solid green;background-color:white;font-size:40px;color:black;padding:15px;}
    .empresa {text-align:center;width:735px;margin-bottom:3px;font-family:Arial;height:75px;border:1px solid green;background-color:white;font-size:40px;color:black;padding:15px;}
    </style>
</head>
<div style="width:770px;border:1px solid gray;padding:15px;background-color:green;">
    <div class="empresa">
        '.template("empresa").'
    </div>
    <div class="descricao">
        '.template("descricao_item_01").'
    </div>
    <div class="especificacao">
        DESCRICAO ---> 01
        PREÇO ----> R$ '.template("preco_item_01").'
    </div>
    <div class="descricao">
        '.template("descricao_item_02").'
    </div>
    <div class="especificacao">
        DESCRICAO ---> 02
        PREÇO ----> R$ '.template("preco_item_02").'
    </div>
    <div class="descricao">
        '.template("descricao_item_03").'
    </div>
    <div class="especificacao">
        DESCRICAO ---> 03
        PREÇO ----> R$ '.template("preco_item_03").'
    </div>
    <div class="descricao">
        '.template("descricao_item_04").'
    </div>
    <div class="especificacao">
        DESCRICAO ---> 04
        PREÇO ----> R$ '.template("preco_item_04").'
    </div>
    <div class="descricao">
        '.template("descricao_item_05").'
    </div>
    <div class="especificacao">
        DESCRICAO ---> 05
        PREÇO ----> R$ '.template("preco_item_05").'
    </div>
    <div class="descricao">
        '.template("descricao_item_06").'
    </div>
    <div class="especificacao">
        DESCRICAO ---> 06
        PREÇO ----> R$ '.template("preco_item_06").'
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;">'.template("cnpj").' - '.template("telefone").'</div>
</div>



    ';
    return $r;
}
```

**O código de enviar o html é:**

```
function sendmail() {
    if(!isset($_POST[Submit])) die("Não foi recebido nenhum parâmetro");
    /* Medida preventiva para evitar que outros domínios sejam remetente da sua mensagem. */
    if (eregi('tempsite.ws$|locaweb.com.br$|hospedagemdesites.ws$|websiteseguro.com$', $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST])) {
            $emailsender=trim($_POST['emailremetente']);
    } else {
            $emailsender = "noreply@" . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST];
    }

    /* Verifica qual é o sistema operacional do servidor para ajustar o cabeçalho de forma correta. Não alterar */
    if(PHP_OS == "Linux") $quebra_linha = "\n";
    elseif(PHP_OS == "WINNT") $quebra_linha = "\r\n";
    else die("Incompatibilidade com Sistema Operacional");

    // Passando os dados obtidos pelo formulário para as variáveis abaixo
    $nomeremetente     = $_POST['nomeremetente'];
    $emailremetente    = trim($_POST['emailremetente']);
    $assunto           = $_POST['assunto'];

    $array_emaildestinatario = array();
    $array_emaildestinatario = explode("\n",trim($_POST['emaildestinatario'])); // separa os emails pelas vírgulas em uma array
    foreach($array_emaildestinatario as $elemento) {
        //pra cada email envia
        /* Montando a mensagem a ser enviada no corpo do e-mail. */
        $mensagemHTML = html();


        /* Montando o cabeçalho da mensagem */
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1".$quebra_linha;
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".$quebra_linha;
        // Perceba que a linha acima contém "text/html", sem essa linha, a mensagem não chegará formatada.
        $headers .= "From: ".$emailsender.$quebra_linha;
        $headers .= "Return-Path: " . $emailsender . $quebra_linha;

        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$emailremetente.$quebra_linha;
        // Note que o e-mail do remetente será usado no campo Reply-To (Responder Para)

        /* Enviando a mensagem */
        mail($elemento, $assunto, $mensagemHTML, $headers, "-r". $emailsender);
    }
    /* Mostrando na tela as informações enviadas por e-mail */
    ?>
        <div style="color:white;border:1px solid black;padding:15px;background-color:rgba(150,50,50,0.8);font-family:Arial;margin-bottom:5px;font-size:14px;">
            Enviando <?php echo count($array_emaildestinatario); ?> e-mails, aguarde um instante...
        </div>
        <div style="color:white;border:1px solid black;padding:15px;background-color:rgba(150,50,50,0.8);font-family:Arial;margin-bottom:5px;font-size:14px;">
            De:<?php echo $emailsender; ?>
        </div>
        <div style="color:white;border:1px solid black;padding-left:15px;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;background-color:rgba(150,50,50,0.3);font-family:Arial;margin-bottom:5px;font-size:14px;">
        <?php 
        foreach($array_emaildestinatario as $elemento) {
            echo "<p>$elemento</p>";
        }
        ?>
        </div>
<?php
}
```

**ELE CHEGA ERRADO NO GMAIL ASSIM: (MEU PROBLEMA ESTA AQUI NO GMAIL)**
[image: HTML BUGADO]
**E NO THUNDERBIRD CHEGA CORRETO ASSIM:**
[image: HTML NAO BUGADO]

**Alguem tem uma solucao?**

Comment: A solução é usar HTML 4, <table>, e praticamente nada de CSS para email.

Comment: Verdade, nada de CSS e se tiver que usar, coloca inline, dentro do código html e não num arquivo a parte. Sempre use para as imagens url's absolutas.

Comment: Eu tive que passar para CSS INLINE, retirando todo meu HEAD para funcionar. Nesse caso a solução que consegui neste momento é melhor que usar HTML 4 Table. 

Mas agora eu queria é carregar um css externo em vez de inline, pelo jeito externo ou no proprio head como estava nao dá entao :/ ?

Valeu pela ajuda pessoal, Marcos Vinicius..., era isso mesmo, INLINE resolveu a primeira viagem. Uma pena ter que usar esse monte de codigo css no meio do meu html.

Comment: Vou fazer o template e depois dele pronto passar pra inline, se eu faço tudo inline fico mais doido que sou apagando e reescrevendo.
Valeu ai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ThunderBird pode ser conflito de codificação com seu PHP (verifique a codificação do seu php se também é 8859-1).

No Gmail pode ser questão de estar usando css inline na head, segundo esse artigo
([aqui](http://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real.../)) ele lista nos itens que não devem ser feitos.

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa usar esses testes de quebra linha. A constante `PHP_EOL` já faz isso.
Você não pode usar estilos externos nem dentro da tag style.

Use uma ferramenta de CSS inliner para fazer isso para você, fica mais fácil.
http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/

Você **não** deve usar codificação ISO-8859-1 como o colega acima falou, e sim Unicode UTF-8 **SEMPRE**, caso não queira ter problemas com acentuação e caracteres estranhos.